# Pagination in Laravel return tables value but not all value of paginate()

Tags: php, json, laravel, pagination

This is my api which is testing in Postman. It returns value but not pagination value.

```
http://localhost/api/v1/projects-data  //This is api
```

here is the image of data which its return to Postman
[image: here is the image of data which its return to Postman]

I put the route code in **api.php**

```
Route::get('all-blogs', 'Api\ApiController@getBlogs');
```

And at last in my **ApiController.php**

```
public function getBlogs(Request $request, Blog $blog = null)
{
    
    if ($blog != null) {
        $blog = Blog::with(['tag', 'comments', 'user'])->where('slug_en', $blog->slug_en)->firstOrFail();
        $blog->increment('views');

        return response()->json(BlogResource::make($blog));
    }
    $blogs = Blog::with([
        'tag', 'comments', 'user',
    ])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    
    return response()->json(BlogResource::collection($blogs));
}
```

And code on **BlogResource.php**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    
    return [
        'id'=>$this->blog_id,
        'keyword' => $this->keyword,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'title' => $this->title,
        'content' => $this->content,
        'content_bare' => strip_tags($this->content, 'ul,li,ol,p,br,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,b,a,span,table,thead,tr,th,td,tfoot,tbody,i,em,strong,strike'),
        'image_url' => $this->image_url,
        'slug' => $this->slug_en,
        'views' => $this->views,
        'created_at' => date('d M Y', strtotime($this->created_at)),
        'ago' => $this->created_at->diffForHumans(),
        'comments' => $this->whenLoaded('comments'),
        'user' => $this->whenLoaded('user'),
        'tag' => $this->whenLoaded('tag'),
    ];
}
```

Every Thing working when i put paginate(5). it's return 5 data in Postman. But Not return other information like **current_page** , **first_page** and so on is not showing.

I need this type of output return

[image: I need this type of output return]

Comment: make such return : return response()->json(["blogs" => $blogs]);

Comment: @Romylussone i want to get data through **BlogResource.php**. Please see **BlogResource.php** code. Thanks

Comment: have you try access to this property using $this and return them as you do with your data (try with $this or $request)

Comment: Just use `return BlogResource::collection($blogs);` no need to wrap in `response()->json(BlogResource::collection($blogs))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are using `return response()->json($resource)`, if you return just the resource (`return $resource`) it will be returned as a `JsonResource` and the pagination metadata will be shown.

Comment: **@pmcpimentel** Thanks, i have only changed on **ApiController.php** with `return response()->json(BlogResource::collection($blogs));` to `return BlogResource::collection($blogs);` . It worked, hurrayyy .Thanks Buddy

Answer (score 1):

You are applying pagination on the `$blogs` variable if you return that variable that will give you paginated answers as you want like page links etc. Currently you are returning resource thats why you are not getting the desired answer.

Comment: **faisal mumtaz** Is there no way to return through resource?

Answer (score 1):

```php
$list = BlogResource::collection($blogs);
$statisticCollection = collect($list);
$sorted = $statisticCollection->paginate(5);
return $sorted;
```

Comment: I don't have compiler currently to test but use this it will sort your issue hopefully and you would get what you want.

Comment: Your code is not working. But i found solution to change `return response()->json(BlogResource::collection($blogs));` to `return BlogResource::collection($blogs);`. It works perfectly